How to "rebase" within a branch to an older commit?
I am using commits to push/pull untested and unfinished code to a private, personal work-in-progress remote repo. That is, these commits serve only to synchronize across devices that I'm working on the code on.
Now I want my IDE to still highlight the code changes with respect to the last commit that was not a "work-in-progress" kind of commit.
Can I "rebase" my branch to such an older commit, such that changes will not be lost, but still highlighted by my IDE with respect to the older commit?
I think rebase is the way to go but the documentation focuses on merging branches.

What is your IDE?  For example, IntelliJ's Git plugin has the ability to show a diff of any file against an earlier version/commit.

@TimBiegeleisen, indeed I use PyCharm
